# How to edit second digit of a 7 figure number in Javascript?

Tags: reactjs, number-formatting

I am working on a ReactJS application and have an input which can have figures in the millions. I am using the following function to format the number with commas:

```
  return Number(number).toLocaleString('en-GB', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

On the onChange prop for the input I have the following to stop the cursor jumping to the end:

```
        const caret = e.target.selectionStart;
        const element = e.target;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          element.selectionStart = caret;
          element.selectionEnd = caret;
        });
```

When trying to change the second figure in one million number `'1,000,000'`, deleting the second zero results in the cursor appearing after the second figure instead of the first figure. How can I make sure the cursor appears in the expected position when deleting digits in a seven-figure number?

Appreciate any advice

Comment: `caret - 1`? A running example will greatly improve your chances of getting a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  const [value, setValue] = useState("1000000");
  const displayValue = Number(value).toLocaleString("en-GB", {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  });

  const handleChange = e => {
    const oldLen = displayValue.length;
    const element = e.target;
    let rawString = element.value;
    let caret = element.selectionStart;

    // block removing decimal point
    if (caret === element.value.length - 2 && element.value.length < oldLen) {
      rawString = rawString.slice(0, caret) + "." + rawString.slice(caret);
    }

    // block removing commas
    if (displayValue.charAt(caret) === "," && rawString.charAt(caret) !== ",") {
      rawString = rawString.slice(0, caret) + "," + rawString.slice(caret);
    }

    const firstCommaAt = rawString.search(/,/g);
    const newLen = rawString.length;

    // caret position correction
    if (newLen > oldLen) {
      if (
        (firstCommaAt === 3 && caret > firstCommaAt) ||
        firstCommaAt === 4 ||
        newLen === 7
      ) {
        caret += 1;
      }
    }
    if (newLen < oldLen) {
      if (firstCommaAt === 1 && caret > firstCommaAt) {
        caret -= 1;
      }
    }

    // store parseable value
    setValue(rawString.replace(/,/g, ""));
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      element.selectionStart = caret;
      element.selectionEnd = caret;
    });
  };

  return (
    <input value={displayValue} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
  )
```

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/input-with-usestate-z48s2